# Spherical cosine law

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

In Sara Seager's book "Exoplanet atmospheres", she uses the spherical cosine law to derive the surface flux. The figure is as follows:

[image: xx]

From the figure, $\hat n \cdot \hat k = \cos \Theta_n$ (where $\hat k$ is in direction of $F$ ($x$-axis)). Using the spherical cosine law, we have $$ \hat n \cdot \hat k = \cos \Theta_n = \cos \theta_n \cos \phi_n$$
How was it derived? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the figure, the projection of $\hat n$ onto the he $x-y$ plane has lenght $|\cos \theta_n|$ and its projection onto the $z$-axis has component $\sin \theta_n$), therefore the components of the unitary vector $\hat n$ with respect to $x$, $y$, $z$ are:

$$\hat n =(\cos \theta_n\cos \phi_n,-\cos \theta_n\sin \phi_n, \sin \theta_n )$$

and then by [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

$$\hat n \cdot \hat k =(\cos \theta_n\cos \phi_n,-\cos \theta_n\sin \phi_n, \sin \theta_n )\cdot(1,0,0)=\cos \theta_n\cos \phi_n$$

Comment: Thanks a million! Now I understand what was done

Comment: Well done! You’re welcome, Bye